# OneDrive and Audio tags Dilemma

Tags: audio, mp3, onedrive, windows-media-player, music

I use WMP and I would like to put all of my music files on OneDrive and let WMP view the Music library from OneDrive.
But when making my music files on OneDrive **online only** to save space, all of the tags (album, artist, genre, etc.) disappears and WMP would view these music files' tags as "Unknown" in its library (except for the song title) making the library not organized in albums, artists, genre, etc.

I can add these tags manually in the WMP library again for each music file and WMP would save these tags, even if the music files are online only on OneDrive.
But suppose I'd like to clean install Windows. This would mean I'd have to add all these tags manually each time after a format. I would therefore need some backup copy of the library information.

I tried backing up the WMP library files (CurrentDatabase_400.wmdb and wmpfolders.wmdb) but when putting these back in the original Appdata directory, WMP still doesn't show the tags of the online-only music files on OneDrive.

Is there any effective way to back up the WMP library which I can put back after a clean install to show the music files organized with all their tags?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an XML backup of the tags in WMP's library with the [Metadata Backup](https://sourceforge.net/projects/metadatabackup/) tool (and restore that backup later on), although I'm not 100% sure if it will play nice with online-only OneDrive music.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I managed to make the backup work. There is one issue though that I noticed. The seekbar can't be used if you play a Onedrive _online only_ audio file from your WMP library. Do you experience the same problem?

Comment: I don't immediately see the relation between backing up and the seekbar, so I assume that your latest question is completely separate and unrelated to backup? My music isn't on OneDrive though, so I don't know if this is a general issue.

Comment: I do remember a similar seeking issue with file types not supported natively by WMP (such as .ogg) in the library, which was due to the playback length for these files not being present in the library. The solution there was to add file type support by installing the WMP Tag Plus plug-in, allowing WMP to read the playback length. But I doubt that WMP Tag Plus will help for online-only files.